# why template substitution fail specifying the namespace of the function to call?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this code, which works as expected:

**serialization.h**

```
#include <QJsonObject>

namespace ns{
QJsonValue serialize(int, Version);
QJsonValue serialize(double, Version);

class ObjectSerializer
{
public:
   template<typename T>
   void insert(const QString& key, const T& value)
   {
      _obj.insert(key, serialize(value));  // <-- Focus here
   }

   QJsonObject object() const { return _obj; }

private:
   QJsonObject _obj;
};
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#include "serialization.h"

namespace ns{
struct Foo{};

QJsonValue serialize(const Foo&, Version) { // ... } 
}
```

**bar.h**

```
#include foo.h

namespace ns{
struct Bar{
  int a;
  Foo f;
};

QJsonValue serialize(const Bar& b, Version)
{
   ObjectSerializer s;
   s.insert("a", b.a);
   s.insert("f", b.f);

   return s.object();
}

}
```

calling `bar.serialize()` works fine because it can deduce correctly the function to call for `int a` and `Foo f`, but if I define `insert()` as follow:

```
   template<typename T>
   void insert(const QString& key, const T& value)
   {
      _obj.insert(key, ns::serialize(value));  // <-- I'm explicitly referring to namespace
   }
```

compiler is still able to deduce to call `serialize(int, Version)` for `bar.a` but not `serialize(const Foo&, Version)` for `bar.f` anymore, signaling a template argument deduction/substitution failed.

Why do this happens?

Comment: Isn't it `::ns::serialize(value)` what you mean?

Comment: @lorro maybe, but why change if everything there is parte of the same namespace?